# How to change the font of paragraph text when using document.getElementById("").innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, fonts

I am building a transcript based off user input and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction of how I might be able to change the font-style of the strings stored in `text_to_add_one` and `text_to_add_two`.

```
if (build_transcript) {
    var text_to_add_one = "<b>" + "YOU: " + "</b>" + `${transcript_you}`;
    var text_to_add_two = "<b>" + "COMPUTER: " + "</b>" + `${transcript_computer}`; 
    document.getElementById("wordsIncluded").innerHTML += "<p>" + text_to_add_one + "</p>" + "<p>"+ text_to_add_two + "</p>" + "</br>";
   build_transcript = false;
}

//wordsIncluded is a div
```

I have tried the approach below but it doesn't seem to work!

```
 document.getElementById("wordsIncluded").innerHTML += "<p id="changeFont">" + text_to_add_one + "</p>" + "<p id="changeFont">" + text_to_add_two + "</p>" + "</br>";
```

CSS FILE

```
#changeFont {
      font-style: 'Quicksand';
}
```

Comment: What is the HTML?

Comment: you are writing the variable as if the id `#changeFont` is generated in JS, so its just a formatting error. either make a variable like `let changeFont = "changeFont";` or format it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing like below.

```js
const transcript_you = "me";
const transcript_computer = "mac";

var text_to_add_one = `<b>YOU: </b>${transcript_you}`;
var text_to_add_two = `<b>COMPUTER: </b>${transcript_computer}`;

document.getElementById(
  "wordsIncluded"
).innerHTML += `<p class="changeFont">${text_to_add_one}</p><p class="changeFont">${text_to_add_two}</p></br>`;
```

```css
p.changeFont {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wordsIncluded"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've used your adjustment, but I just changed the class to `style="font-family: 'Quicksand'` just cause it's easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `"<p id="changecolor">"`. As the code coloring shows, it does not matter part of the string. You should use `"<p id=\"changecolor\">"` or `'<p id="changecolor">'`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use single quotes .

```
document.getElementById("wordsIncluded").innerHTML += '<p id="changeFont">' + text_to_add_one + '</p>' + '<p id="changeFont">' + text_to_add_two + '</p>' + '</br>';
```

Comment: Single quotes didn't seem to work for me for some reason but I fixed the issue nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

This also works by the way and I'll probably use this just because I can see what font-family I will be using:

```
document.getElementById("wordsIncluded").innerHTML += `<p style="font-family: 'Quicksand'; class="changeFont">${text_to_add_one}</p><p style="font-family: 'Quicksand'; class="changeFont">${text_to_add_two}</p></br>`;
```